# How can Excel file and website server interact?

Tags: excel, web, server, frontend, backend

I have a working excel calculator and a website server. My goal is to present the result generated by the calculator on the website. And to feed input received by the website My question is that how should I implement this because excel and website server can not seem to interact directly. 
I am looking for some language that the excel can be converted to and the language can also be interactive with a website.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed excel documents on a website using one drive or google docs.

Sync your doc to your one drive, then embed the doc on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, we are required to transform the excel calculator to a program written in another language that the website back-end can interact with. Could you maybe suggest some languages to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mentioned excel calculator means the Excel that include many formula.
If it is true, you can use Excel component library. Use Excel library load Excel file, and Excel library can calculate result based on website input parameter.

I used to two products you can reference, SpreadJS and GcExcel.
SpreadJS is front-side library, it is based on JavaScript.
GcExcel is server-side library, it has Java version and .NET version.

OK, if you choose the front side library. Whole operation can be implemented by JS code.

If you choose server-side library. In website page, you can receive the input parameter, then transfer these data to server. In server, load Excel and calc result, at last pass back the result to front-side.